# For single product: React TypeError: Cannot read property ‘map’ of undefined :

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

This is a single product data .

```
const [single, setSingle]= useState([])

setSingle(res.data) (axios set state)


{
  "id": 135,
  "device_detail": [
    {
      "type": "high-speed",
      "brief": "dsf",
      "model": "ds",
      "serial": "ds"
    },
    {
      "type": "low-speed",
      "brief": "dfg",
      "model": "hgj",
      "serial": "dsf"
    }
  ],
  "device_name": "Handpieces",
  "practice_name": "dsf",
  "unit": "dsf",
  "street": "dsf",,
  "status": 1,
  "created_at": "2021-03-02 14:00:58.295738+00:00"
}
```

When i use

```
{single.device_detail.map((subd,index)=>(
(index ? ', ' : '') + subd.type
 ))}
```

its saying TypeError: Cannot read property ‘map’ of undefined :

but when i make another state for device_detail and then its working like this:

```
const [dd, setdd]= useState([])

setdd(res.data.device_detail) (axios set state)
```

But, i this is not a proper solution.

Any idea?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and what confused you.

Comment: Please check the current one. i just edited the question.

Comment: Can you please share the complete fragment of the code in any plnkr, sandbox or any cloud editor. 

The error is because the compiler not reading device_detail as an array type. Is not getting single as an object, this mean that single context is undefined.

Please share a complete fragment of the section where you calling the single object, becase those "{ }" looks like destructring or I do not know if is a starting of a function or what.

Comment: *    const [single, setSingle]= useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(props.api_path, {headers:props.headers})
        .then((res) => {
            setSingle(res.data)
           
            console.log(res.data)
        })
        .catch((err) =>{
            console.log(err)
        }) 
    },[]);*

Comment: Single is getting as an object. but device detail is also getting as an object not as a array.

Comment: Put your code [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66451990/edit), not in comments.